# What are SPI sequences, jobs and channels? (Examples)

Tags: autosar

All I know is:

> - 1 sequence can have 1 or more jobs;
> - 1 job can have 1 or more channels;
> - 1 channel has 1 Tx memory buffer and 1 Rx memory buffer;

Answer (score 1):

This question refers to the software-level implementation of the SPI protocol - presumably for the AUTOSAR SPI driver.

> A **Channel** is a software exchange medium for data that are defined with the same criteria: Configuration Parameters, Number of Data elements with the same size and data pointers (Source & Destination) or location.
>
> A **Job** is composed of one or several Channels. it's considered atomic and therefore cannot be interrupted by another job. it's a basic SPI command.
>
> a **sequence** is a general routine like reading, erase, write. it contains a set of jobs that should be executed sequentially. A Sequence communication is interruptible (by another Sequence of communication).

[(From the Autosar standard - SPI driver/handler specification)](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/standards/R22-11/CP/AUTOSAR_SWS_SPIHandlerDriver.pdf)